# Storing Spectrograms is very storage expensive

Tags: python, spectrogram, mfcc

I'm very desperate with a coding/architecture problem here, maybe you can help me.
I currently try to compare different representations of data in the music genre classification with each other (because of my bachelor thesis).
So what do I do exactly?

I take a dataset (e.g. GTZAN), and transform the WAV Files to MFCCs, and store it in a JSON file, that works perfectly and doesn't eat to much storage.
After that, I try to transform the WAV Files to Spectrograms and store it in the same way, but it needs like 1.5 GB for 20 Spectrograms, BUT I NEED 8000 :(
Why is it so storage-expensive to save an spectrogram, compared to an MFCC?

Here is the code to create and store the MFCC:

```
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(signal[start_sample:finish_sample],
                                                sr = sr,
                                                n_fft = n_fft,
                                                n_mfcc = n_mfcc,
                                                hop_length=hop_length)
mfcc = mfcc.T
if len(mfcc) == expected_num_mfcc_vectors_per_segment:
                        data["mfcc"].append(mfcc.tolist())
                        data["labels"].append(i-1)
                        print("{}, segment:{}".format(file_path, s+1))
                        logging.debug("{}, segment:{}".format(file_path, s+1))
    with open(json_path, "w") as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)
```

Here is the code for the spectrogram:

```
signal, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=SampleRate)
                stft = librosa.stft(signal, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length)
                spec = np.abs(stft) ** 2
                log_scale_spec = librosa.power_to_db(spec)
                data["spectrogram"].append(log_scale_spec.tolist())
                data["labels"].append(i-1)
    with open(json_path, "w") as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)
```

SOLVED: I solved it in another way. I didn't storaged the spectrograms in a JSON-Object, I just saved them as Images.
Here's the code:

```
def plot_spectrogram(samples, label, filename):
    stft = librosa.core.stft(samples, hop_length=HopLength, n_fft=NFFT)
    spectrogram = np.abs(stft)
    librosa.display.specshow(spectrogram, sr=SampleRate, hop_length=HopLength)
    log_spectrogram = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spectrogram)
    librosa.display.specshow(log_spectrogram, sr=SampleRate, hop_length=HopLength)
    save_image(plt, SpectrogramPath, label, filename)
    plt.show()
    

def save_image(plot, rootpath, label, filename):
    newpath = os.path.join(rootpath, label, filename)
    print("Create new Image: {}", newpath)
    figure = plot.gcf()
    figure.set_size_inches(5,3)
    plot.axis('off')
    plot.savefig(newpath, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
```

Comment: The mel frequency cepstral coefficients (MFCCs) of a signal are a small set of features (usually about 10-20) which concisely describe the overall shape of a spectral envelope. A spectrogram is a time dependent visual representation of the frequencies associated with an audio signal stream.  So every MFCC will be composed of a small condensed set of attributes whereas the spectrogram will be composed of a 3d array including time, freq, freq amplitude thus the spectrogram will be larger than the original audio file

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved it via saving the Images instead of the JSON Object. Your hint was very useful!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved the issue.